# Getting message "Composer could not find a composer.json file" installing Laminas skeleton application

Tags: php, composer-php, laminas

Ran the tutorial on starting a Laminas project on this page: https://docs.laminas.dev/tutorials/getting-started/skeleton-application/.  Got the error shown below after running this command:

```
composer create-project -s dev laminas/laminas-mvc-skeleton path/to/install
```

Here is the exact error that appeared (directory path has been sanitized):

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   Composer could not find a composer.json file in /path/to/project
>   To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as
>   described in    the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

Answer (score -3):

The solution is absurdly simple.  Restate the above command, but remove the space between "-s" and "dev":

```
composer create-project -sdev laminas/laminas-mvc-skeleton path/to/install
```